# How to move a map using Map press easy Google plugins

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, plugins

I'm currently building a website using wordpress. I used Map press easy Google plugins for include a map in my contact tab. However, I want to put for example the map to the left and a form to the right. But I don't find any features which can allow me to move it. I tried to use the .css file but I don't have any html take to select.
Here is my website with my map:

http://hernehillintersport.co.uk/contact/

and here's the code provide by the plugin that I insert into my contact page:

> [mappress mapid="1"]

Does who is using this plugin can help me ? Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input this code into your css file:

```
    input {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    #mapp0_layout{
        width: 43%;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 5%;
    }

    div.wpcf7 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 51%;
        float: right;
    }

    textarea {
    width: 100% !important;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! :) It work perfectly except that as you can see ( please check the link again)  the text start to be display between the map and the form. I tried to put it on the bottom on the page using "bottom" in css but doesn't work